# Sas splitting a row in multiple rows using different variables

Tags: sql, sas

How can I split a row in multiple rows using different variables ?

The problem here is that I have comas inside quotes so I can't just scan a coma. I tried scanq but it doesn't work neither.

```
ID    SENTENCE
1     "I live with my family, and my dog, and my cat", cow, rockstar
2     others
```

And I would like

```
ID    SENTENCE
1     I live with my family, and my dog and my cat
1     cow
1     rockstar
2     others
```

Thanks for any tips !

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern now-a-days is to `scan` throught a `countw` of the *sentence*.

The `COUNTW` and `SCAN` functions have arguments for

- specifying the separator character(s)
- specifying modifiers for function operation, including

  - The `Q` modifier *"ignores delimiters that are inside substrings thatare enclosed in quotation marks. If the value of string containsunmatched quotation marks, scanning from left to right produces differentwords than scanning from right to left."*

Use example:

Specify comma delimiter and `Q` modifier

```
data have;
  input;
  id + 1;
  line = _infile_;
datalines;
"I live with my family, and my dog, and my cat", cow, rockstar
others
;

data want(keep=id index line_part);
  set have;
  do index = 1 to countw(line,',','Q');
    line_part = dequote(scan(line,index,',','Q'));
    OUTPUT;
  end;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your input !, but this strategy is using scanq since scanq is scan with the 'q' argument. Anyway I managed to do that by doing an other file with every possibilities. Then i did a left join with findw. Thanks again, I learned the dequote function thanks to you (didn't work in my current dataset but mbe later !)